# Can't upgrade debian stretch php to 7.x

Tags: php, apache2

I need to upgrade my server (debian 9) php version from 7.0 to 7.1 at least, but it seems that apt doesn't find any version.
I did:

```
apt update
apt upgrade
```

And now if I do `apt install php7` or
`apt install php 7.1` (or 7.2 or 7.3 or 7.4)
or even
`apt install php 7.0` (that is the installed version)
I have that message:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package php7.3
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'php7.3'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php7.3'
```

Something must be broken but I don't find, I googled but I only find for ubuntu that it is needed to add `ppa:ondrej`

EDIT: I understand that I should update debian to 10 because debian 9 is no more supported and that it's risky (for most cases) to keep out of date sofwtares.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nothing is broken. Debian 9 is simply not supported anymore, and has  [never included PHP7.3](https://packages.debian.org/search?suite=stretch&keywords=php).

> Debian 9 has been superseded by Debian 10 ("buster"). Security updates have been discontinued as of July 6th, 2020.

[From Debian's page on Stretch](https://www.debian.org/releases/stretch/). In short; upgrade to Debian 10. Debian 9 is not supported any more, and running a web server on a unsupported OS is crazy.

Comment: They block also old available packages ? Doesn't Debian 9 supports php7.1 ? How can I install it anyway ?

Comment: No, they don't block anything. But the packages you are looking for are not in the repositories. If you want newer versions, you have to check backports, or third party repositories. And to repeat: don't run Debian 9. Upgrade.

Comment: Thank you but I afraid about upgrading and braking thing that work... I find how to upgrade to 8.0 : https://blog.programster.org/debian-9-upgrade-to-php-7-3

Comment: Questions should demonstrate reasonable information technology management practices. Questions that relate to unsupported hardware or software platforms or unmaintained environments may not be suitable for Server Fault. first upgrade then use the software

Comment: It's not stupid. running out of date software is a security risk and leads to weird problems. If you're prepared to handle running out of date software, that's fine, but being prepared to do that should include knowing how to handle it.